# Multiple SaaS Solution Integrations with On Prem Systems

Tags: software-as-a-service, integration

I am looking at a couple of SaaS Policy Solutions and want to integrate those with an On Prem Policy System.

I am listing some goals below and approach I am considering. I am looking for any input on this approach / suggestions.

**Goals:**

1. Create REST Apis that will return data from any of these 3 systems
2. The data returned from the Api should handle data from any of the 3 systems (so that the consumer does not have to call multiple Apis - hide the fact there are 3 systems)
3. To the consumer of the Api they have No Idea the data is from one or more systems.

**Possible apporach:**

1. Replicate the SaaS data (real-time) to the on prem system
2. Process that data through a transformation layer and populate a set of tables *(a model we define to combine the 3 systems)*
3. REST Apis obtain the data from #2 (transformed data). (meaning no transformation in the Apis, just interfaces/mapping/returned data.

This would be challenging to "fit" the model to three systems. But at the same time this transformation would seem to have to be at the database level to provide the Api with decent performance.